# how to change the default animation from right to left for series in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, highcharts

How to change the default animation from right to left for series in high charts as animation:false will remove animation and by default whenever chart loads its from left to right but i want it from right to left..

I am adding the link in addition to that which captures live data and then it is displayed in high charts.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/

```
 `$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function () {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function () {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = Math.random();
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                data: (function () {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: Math.random()
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                }())
            }]
        });
    });
});`
```

Comment: it's already from right to left in the js fiddle !!!

Comment: While loading its not like that ..as soon as we click on run it gets triggered from left to right and then it goes that way.

Comment: Do you mean that xAxis should be reversed and animation too ?

Comment: No,  plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    compare: 'percent'
                },
                line: {
                    animation: false
                }
            },
like in this case whenever the chart gets loaded there will not be any animation while redrawing chart but if we make this animation:true then it'll be drawn from left to right which is default behaviour of Highchart. Basically, I want to reverse the direction of animation while loading the chart. I am not sure whether this is supported in highchart or not so kindly help me finding it out.

Comment: Is there anyone who knows how the required animation will work?? Please help